Macro in Basic for LibreOfficeWriter: make a textframe for each bookmark
I have a Writer document, that has bookmarks (It's a theater play, the bookmarks are the number of each verse).
I'd like to make each bookmarks visible, I am thinking about creating a textFrame for each bookmark that has the bookmark's name as text.
As I do not know anything about macros on Writer, I asked Google's Gemini for help. As expected, there's always something that does not work.
The latest version Gemini proposed is:
Sub CreateTextFramesForBookmarks()
    Dim document As Object
    Dim bookmarks As Object
    Dim bookmark As Object
    Dim textFrame As Object

    document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    bookmarks = document.Bookmarks

    For Each bookmark In bookmarks
        textFrame = document.Text.createTextFrame()
        textFrame.Text.String = bookmark.Name
        textFrame.Anchor.gotoRange(bookmark.Start, False)
    Next bookmark
End Sub

which result with the error Property or method not found: Bookmarks for the line bookmarks = document.Bookmarks.
So apparently, it manages to get the bookmarks, and the issue is now instantiating a new textFrame.
Any idea?
Thanks for reading!

Perhaps this is case-sensitive. Try changing Bookmarks into bookmarks.

Please don't post AI-generated code, especially not for LibreOffice macros because AI tends to struggle with those. We can all get more than enough generated code, and in most cases it leads to rabbit trails, worse than posting no code at all. What would be helpful is any attempt you tried, based on documents you read. "As I do not know anything about macros on Writer" -- A good place to start is Andrew Pitonyak's macro document. Search through the document for a particular snippet that is related to what you're trying to do.
